# Cat and a mouse on a circle

Tags: soft-question, puzzle

I hope this is the right plcae to post it as I'm not sure if the solution is mathematical. I saw this riddle on a board at the university and it seems that there's something I'm missing. It goes as follows:

> As cat and a mouse are running on $10m$ circle at speed of $1\frac{m}{s}$.
>   They can each change their direction in notime. Will the
>   cat catch the mouse?

I can't see why the mouse can't change its direction everytime it goes near the cat, but I guess this is not the answer.

Comment: Can the mouse know where the cat is? And is the radius or the circumference $10m$?

Comment: @user202729: The size of the circle surely has no bearing on the answer?

Comment: If I am understanding the riddle correctly, then (assuming that the starting position is not the same) the mouse should just run in the same direction as the cat, at each time, and then, as they run at the same speed, their distance will remain equal to the starting one...

Comment: Of course the question becomes much more interesting if you are asking/allowing for the mouse and the cat to move on a Disk (so not just on the boundary). In that case, in infinite time, the cat will catch the Mouse :P

Comment: @b00nheT I think in that case, if travelling at the same speed and the mouse always travels in the same direction as the cat (and the cat always takes the shortest pathway b/w them at all times), then the mouse would move towards the edge of the disk until it hits the edge, giving the cat a small time to catch up to the mouse. Then they would both travel along the boundary indefinitely. The initial distance between the cat and mouse would determine if the cat catches the mouse. This distance must be ≥ the the distance the cat gains on the mouse once the mouse reaches the edge of the disk.

Comment: @b00nheT the cat gets a small chance to catch up because once the mouse hits the edge, then the cat can still travel directly towards the mouse at the same speed while the mouse has some direction towards the center of the circle, since it *must* travel along the edge of the disk, while the cat can travel just a bit more directly towards the mouse before it hits the edge.

To answer the OP's question, I think the cat would never catch the mouse as long as their starting point is different, simply because they traverse the circle at the same speed.

Comment: I think the question requires more details.